# How to order a variable depending on the mean of another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, boxplot

I have a database in which 30000 observations of 30000 students from 75 schools are stored. Each school is defined by its own code, for example, you see below the scores of 5 students of the same school defined by the code "01302P".

[image]

But, there are many other schools (75 in total), and for each school we have a specific code.

Then, we calculate the mean of the scores of all the students of each school,meaning we have a table of 75 meanscores for every school, this meanscore would allow us to compare the performance of each school.

Now what I am trying to do is to order the schools depending of their meanscore, I tried this code:

```
boxplot(moy_exam2~CODEETAB,epl_data,las=2,main="schools order",xlab = NULL,ylab = "Mean of score (moy_exam2)",col = 'red')
```

It generates this boxplot, I can tell which school is the best in terms of the mean score of their students, it the one with the code "51680Y", but I can't do more than that ! because the plot is so full of schools and I can't see the order clearly.

But I need a way to get all the schools ordered depending on their mean score results,

Also I would prefer to use ggplot2 library to enhance the code

Please help and thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can order the schools based on their mean score (underneath done with dplyr) and then assign that order of schools as factor levels for the schools.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  schools = rep(LETTERS[1:20], 20),
  scores = rnorm(400, sample(1:400))
)

means <- group_by(df, schools) %>%
  summarise(mu = mean(scores)) %>%
  arrange(mu)

df %>%
  mutate(schools = factor(schools, levels = means$schools)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(schools, scores)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks dude, but I get this error : Error in mean(scores) : object 'scores' not found
I think there is a problem in the summerise function line

  summarise(mu = mean(scores))

Answer (score 1):

Route you can take: Calculate mean score for the schools:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
group_by(schools) %>%
summarize(score_mean = mean(scores)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
arrange(desc(score_mean))
```

After this you can use the new DF for creating the visual. Also dont forget to replace the variable names